# ListView using volley

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-volley

I'm trying to connect sql server to android studio using json here is my code.
I don't have any error on android studio but when I test it I got the error message "Error in connection" on my phone.
How can I fix this problem?

**MainActivity**

```
List<RowItem> rowItems=new ArrayList<RowItem>();
ListView mylistview;
private CustomAdapter adapter;
JSONArray peoples = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    subject();
}

public void subject(){
    String url = "http://myIP-Here/MSSQL/client.php";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.d("************", response);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("response",response);

                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray("json");
                        mylistview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

                        adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, rowItems);

                        mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);
                        for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++) {
                            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);

                            RowItem goodsItems = new  RowItem();
                            goodsItems.setItem_id(c.getInt("item_id"));
                           goodsItems.setItem_name(c.getString("item_name"));



                            rowItems.add(goodsItems);

                            mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error in connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("response","error");
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            //params.put("UserEmail", get_email);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

**CustomAdapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private  List<RowItem> rowItems;
Typeface font;


public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, List<RowItem> rowItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.rowItems =rowItems;
}

Context context;
public CustomAdapter(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return rowItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    TextView item_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_id);
    TextView item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
 //   ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imView);

    final RowItem m = rowItems.get(position);

   // Picasso.with(activity)
     //       .load(m.get_image())
       //     .resize(300, 300)
         //   .into(image);
  item_id.setText(m.getItem_id());
    item_name.setText(m.getItem_name());
    return convertView;
}
public void clearAdapter()
{
    rowItems.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

**RowItem**

```
public class RowItem {
public int  item_id;
public String  item_name;
public int img;

public RowItem(){
   this.item_id=item_id;
    this.item_name=item_name;}
  public int   getItem_id() {return item_id;}
public void setItem_id(int item_id) { this.item_id=item_id; }

public String  getItem_name() {return item_name;}
public void setItem_name(String item_name) { this.item_name=item_name; }
```

I also have photos on my sql database stored as varbinary(MAX) which I want to display on my listView, I really need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

1. Check your device is connected to the internet which makes the request to the server and on the same network when testing in LAN network.
2. Check you have disabled the firewall of the server if you are connected in LAN.
3. Check the URL where you are sending the request.

Comment: I'm new to android studio and logcat doesn't help, I can't find any error:(

Comment: Don't Worry We Will Find A Solution, Have you edited the code yet? @EnasAK

Comment: Check The Logcat By Searching It From The Logcat panel, if you did not get this then, please reply

Comment: I found it, what I am looking for in the logcat?

Comment: You need to search for the keyword `response`. you will get your error there.

Comment: This Means Your Device Is Not Able To Connect With The Server, Check The Edited Answer Above.

Comment: ` I/response: error :-java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` I got this

Comment: How are you running your app? I mean in a real device or emulator

Comment: on real device @Shashank

Comment: So are you connected to the same network on the device which you have connected to the server?

Comment: Try Opening Your URL in device's browser.

Comment: I tried,  I disabled my firewall but it is not working

Comment: What's not working? Is it not opening in the browser. And If Not Then what's the error showing on the browser.

Comment: My connection is working now, but the listView on my phone still empty, and I got nothing in Logcat `I/response: error :-null` so maybe there is something wrong with my code. @Shashank

Comment: Good, Now it is maybe the problem of server-side code, check the logcat of the server.

Comment: Plese, do tick my answer as correct if it helped you, Welcome.

Comment: Will you please describe me how you solved ther error?

Comment: I will choose it :) ,I added my port number after the IP address and disabled my firewall, I changed this line  `item_id.setText(m.getItem_id());` to `item_id.setText(String.valueOf(m.getItem_id()));` the last thing I deleted the padding attribute on my xml file

Comment: See I Have Written In My Answer That Check The URL Where You Are Sending The Request And The Firewall Thing As Well.